# Google Sheets API returns 404

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am following the [Google Docs API for javascript example](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) to the letter, and got the basic example working. I have an api key, a secret token and I have set which ip addresses can access the data (http://localhost).

The demo works, it shows an auth button and after authenticating I can download google's example data using:

```
// google data example
var sheetId = "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms"

// load and show data
gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
          spreadsheetId: sheetId,
          range: 'Class Data!A2:E',
        }).then(function(response) {
          console.log("loaded data " + response);
        });
```

The problem is that if I replace the sheet id with the id of my own google docs sheet, I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404`.

I have even made my own sheet public. You can view it straight in any browser without even logging in. But even then I can't load the data using the API! (I don't want my sheet to be public though).

What step am I missing to connect to my own data?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To actually make the [Sheets Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) work for your own spreadsheet, make sure you've done these things:

1. Start a local webserver like `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080` so you actually have a connection to the internet.
2. Provide the correct SpreadSheet ID
3. Provide the correct sheet name, as well as sheetname in [A1Notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation).
4. Provide the correct sheet range in A1 Notation.

   (I also removed the API KEY variables)

   And here's the screenshot that I got it working:

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, I have followed all the instructions literally. I have provided my own api key and secret and then it still works, with google's example sheet. Then, I copied google's example sheet into my own sheet so it has the exact same contents. But it still won't load, I get a 404 error or a 400 error.

Comment: I found the error, my sheet copy wasn't named `Class Data` so that's why the request `range: 'Class Data!A2:E'` failed. I thought `class data` was just some kind of API call but it was actually the name of the sheet... :-/